# Fido2 for Windows Hello

Tags: windows, active-directory, schema, fido, fido-u2f

I want to leverage my windows hello by fido2 security key. but all I saw on internet is somehow dealing with azure active directory. Whereas I wanna extend schema in windows server active directory and have windows signing challenge with fido2 security key interacting with local domain.so I want to know what to do and what is procedure?

I extended schema with some attributes and finally added those attributes and class to users domain. but it didn't work . it seems windows hello doesn't sent any query to  active directory domain services(AD DS).

Comment: Can you please expand on what you're trying to accomplish and include a topology? It is not clear.

Comment: I'm in a project to use fido2 security key like solo key or YubiKey to sign into the windows. but I don't want to deal with azure active directory At all , instead I'm trying to use active directory domain services in windows server which is powered by extended schemas related to fido2 credential and fido2 public key but there are some problems .